# Event sequence in node cluster

Tags: node.js, node-cluster

In node cluster docs there are few events that is called by cluster. Out of which 'online' and 'listening' is two events that I am confused about which is being called first.

there is a line written

> The difference between 'fork' and 'online' is that fork is emitted
>   when the master forks a worker, and 'online' is emitted when the
>   worker is running.

So what is the exactly difference between `running` and `listening`